# How to access and modify complex list/dictionary data structure in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am trying to analyze web server logs to get IP addresses, user agents, request paths data. I would like to store different paths visited by a particular IP. In addition, some clients spoof user agents so an IP can present many user agent strings. I would like to store this user agent and  path  data for each IP.

Right now I have created a data structure as follows:

```
ip_dict[ip_address] = [ total_count_int, [{'path_name_1': path_name_1-count_int }, {'path_name_2': path_name_2_count} ], [ {'crawler': crawler_count_int} ]  ]
```

First item in the list - Total number of requests
Second item in the list - List of `{'visited site path' : count }`
Third item in the list - List of `{'visited user agent' : count }`

However, it's getting complicated to implement it for modifying existing items. I would like to increment count if respective key element matches.

Any help on creating better data structure or modifying elements in above data structure would be appreciated.

Comment: First things first dont use dashes in your variable names. Use underscores only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a dict of dicts is what you want:

```
def update(ip_dict, ip_address, site_path, user_agent):
    if ip_address in ip_dict:
        ip_entry = ip_dict[ip_address]

        ip_entry['total_count'] += 1

        if site_path in ip_entry['site_paths']:
            ip_entry['site_paths'][site_path] += 1
        else:
            ip_entry['site_paths'][site_path] = 0

        if user_agent in ip_entry['user_agents']:
            ip_entry['user_agents'][user_agent] += 1
        else:
            ip_entry['user_agents'][user_agent] = 0
    else:
        ip_dict[ip_address] = {
            'total_count': 1,
            'site_paths': {site_path: 1},
            'user_agent': {user_agent: 1}
        }

# initialize the ip dict
ip_dict = {}

# read from your log file and for every entry, call
update(ip_dict, '1.2.3.4', site_path, user_agent)
```

Of course, you can optimize this by using `defaultdict`, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you gorus. I had started with dict of dicts, but I was getting lost in implementing. Your example cleared my confusion.